# fish autocomplete file path without specifying directory structure

Tags: zsh, fish, zsh-completion

I recently switched over to fish shell and want to know whether it can autocomplete file paths as in zsh without specifying it's parent directories. For a file in `foo/bar/file.ext`, in zsh, I can type `open .///file <TAB>` and autocomplete to `open ./foo/bar/file.ext` (assuming no other similarly named file or directory sits at the same level). When I do the same thing in fish, the autocomplete cannot find the file. Is there a way to enable this in fish?

Comment: How does `./*/*/file<tab>` sound?

Answer (score 2):

Not in the same manner as zsh. Fish has a special `**` glob that recurses into directories. And the autocompletion logic recognizes and handles it. So you can do `open **/file[tab]` and it will provide you with matching files to choose from. However, it doesn't actually expand the `**` on the command line which leaves the results somewhat ambiguous. We have an open issue, https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/751, to implement a way to explicitly ask that vars and globs be expanded before running the command.

Comment: I see. Is is planned to mimic zsh in the future? I found that `open **/file <TAB>` is much slower than zsh. Does the autocompletion become faster as I use the shell more?

Comment: As a general rule the fish team does not add configurable behavior. The shell should "just work". We are willing to change existing behavior if someone makes a proposal for new behavior that is clearly superior and the change is unlikely to annoy more than a tiny percentage of users accustomed to the existing behavior. Please open an issue: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/new. Recursive file completion using `**` is slow the first time because the OS may have to read a lot of data off disk.